# How to get new post URL?

Tags: posts, functions, themes, wp-admin

I'm wondering... how can I get the new post URL in my theme? Is there a built-in function for this?

So, it should return something like http://example.com/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=post.

Connor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
admin_url('post-new.php');
```

The [`admin_url`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/admin_url) function will handle generating most of the link, you just need to give it the final component. You can pass in `GET` parameters as well. Just look at the backend URL to see what you need.

```
admin_url('post-new.php?post_type=page');
```

Or using [`add_query_arg`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg) as suggested by @Rarst ...

```
add_query_arg(array('post_type'=>'page'),admin_url('post-new.php'));
```

It is overkill for simple URLs but useful for dynamic ones.

Comment: Thank you! This works like a charm. I'd vote you up, but I need more rep. When I get some more, I'll vote you up :)

Comment: There is also [`add_query_arg()`](http://queryposts.com/function/add_query_arg/) for adding more complex `GET` argument sets to URL.