# Create Add New button

Tags: wp-list-table

How to create Add New button in WP_List_Table Class ?

[image]

Comment: This question is way too vague. Please provide more information on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the "Add new" part, here's an example that I assume will help you. I haven't used WP_List_Table so unfortunately I can't comment much on that. But based on the [class reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table) I'd guess you'd need to use the `get_columns()` method.

Using the code below you should be able to generate an url that you can use as `href` for an `a` tag. You can then render the `a` wherever you need it to be.

```
admin_url('post-new.php?post_type={post_type}');
```

When clicked, the genereated url should take the user to "Add new {post_type}" editing view.

Example copied from, [How to get new post URL?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/104708/how-to-get-new-post-url)